# Pass argument from link button to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, .net

Unable to pass an argument from asp LinkButton to the javascript function I am calling it from OnClientClick.

This is what I have so far

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject") %>' OnClientClick ="OpenViewMeeting(this); return false;" CommandName="Id" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("Id") %>' Width ="30%"/>
```

Javascript Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenViewMeeting(Ob) {
        var Id = Ob.CommandArgument;
        alert(Id);
        return false;
    }
    </script>
```

I can get the text of the button using "ob.text", so I know that "this" actually passes the LinkButton. However, I am trying to catch an argument from it and not the text. I need javascript for some further purpose, so I need to catch the argument there. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommandArgument is strictly server side and does not show up in rendered html, how ever you could add an attribute named "CommandArgument" or whatever you wanted in the Page_PreRender and then pass it the bound CommandArgument value like this:

```
LinkButton lb = Repeater1.Controls[index of the reapeater item].FindControl("LinkButton2") as LinkButton;
lb.Attributes.Add("CommandArgument", lb.CommandArgument);
```

Comment: You are right, CommandArgument is completely a server-side property and doesn't render any html attribute. I was able to make it work through code behind. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In code behind you can do this as well,

```
LinkButton2.Attributes.Add("onclick","javascript:return OpenViewMeeting("+LinkButton2.ID+")");
```

Comment: I am having a hard time to pass the "Id" of that "Subject" to code behind @NZets520

Comment: aren't you forgetting something, i mean runat="server" ? Just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

If `CommandArgument` becames an html attribute you can try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenViewMeeting(Ob) {
    var Id = Ob.getAttribute("CommandArgument");
    alert(Id);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Otherwise inspect your html source and see how it looks and detect you attribute name.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, as someone else answered, CommandArgument is completely a server-side property and doesn't render any html attribute. So you can't change any button's attribute and fire click on it. I finally made "Id" come through the code behind and made it work.

Answer (score 0):

As per [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479430/jquery-pass-asp-button-command-argument-with-jquery) Question And Answer.

`CommandArgument` is completely a server-side property and doesn't render any html attribute. So you can't change any button's attribute and fire click on it. The good news is that you can fire `postback` with client-side `__doPostBack` function using `__doPostBack("<%= btn1.UniqueID %>", val);`

> please the the link.

Comment: You are right. I finally made "Id" come through the code behind and made it work.Thanks for that link and info.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the parameter  "this" in your java script function is as follows. it pass the DOM object of your rendered Link button. It means this parameter can get any HTML attribute in your link button.  CommandArgument is a server property, any of these server properties is not understandable to Java script. i don't know what is your exact purpose with this id, any way just to get the ID of your link button (ID generated in HTML, not the Server ID , if you use a master page the server id and ID in rendered HTML will differ), you may just call as follows

```
<script>
        function OpenViewMeeting(thisObj) {
            alert(thisObj.id);
        }
 </script>
```