# cannot get the newest button name in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

my asp project has a asp button which named 'Save'. However, i need to change it to 'Update' in jQuery to do other thing in one button.

The problem is the C# onclick code is still read it as Save..

Code:

```
//Main
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save" />

//JQuery
 $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").val("Update");

//C#
 var button = sender as Button;
var buttonName = button.Text; //Save
```

**Update1**

Question is:
I need to change the button name in JQuery

```
$("#<%=btnChangeName.ClientID %>").click({
     $("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").val("Update"); //Change Save to Update
});
```

Then use it in C#:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              var button = sender as Button;
              var buttonName = button.Text;
              if (buttonName == "Save")
              {//something}
              else
              {//something}
        }
```

Comment: If you change the Button.OnClick value, then it will move to a different method onClick; Button.Text = "Update";Button.OnClick = "ButtonUpdate";/Button.Text="Save";Button.OnClick="ButtonSave";

Comment: @kingyau why cant u change thae name in the button_click itself

Comment: @Webruster In my form, user can either create new item by selecting create => "Save" or update existing item by selecting edit => "Update"

Comment: @kingyau  got it, will give u solution !!

Comment: Why not set the button text in the code behind on page load? If a user selects an item to edit, set `button.Text = "Update";`, otherwise `button.Text = "Save";`.

Comment: @BryanWoodford because any postback will destroy my code until the user clicks the save/ update button.

Comment: @kingyau - Surely, on postback, you will have the saved object and can change the value of the button accordingly?

Comment: @BryanWoodford i also have plan bcdefg (e.g. double button hidden one ) if it is not possible to get the new button name. Moreover, i want my website has less refreshing.

Comment: @kingyau - I was going to suggest having two buttons as an alternative :)

Comment: You really don't need to change the text - just call it save/update and test for existing record in the onclick; save if no, update if yes.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger Hey, i found this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479430/jquery-pass-asp-button-command-argument-with-jquery). Will it fits to my case?

Comment: It looks as though it might, but it surely seems like you're reinventing the wheel. My answer(below) seems a lot more C-A-T = "Cat" as opposed to C-A-T = "Felus F. Catus." If you drop-dead want to do it with JQuery then it looks like you're on the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change the Name to `Update1` in Jquery

try like this

```
$("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>").val('Update');
```

Event you neeed to use is **OnClientClick**

Usage example

```
OnClientClick="onupd();return false;"
```

**Update**

Decalre a **Hidden FIeld**

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdntest" Value="0" />
```

assign the button change value to update and assign it to the hidden field

not access that hidden value in your code behind.

you can assign **Button value** to **Hidden Field** like this

```
$("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").val("Update");

 $("#<%=hdntest.ClientID%>").val($("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>").attr("value"));
```

Comment: i need to use its name in server side to do thing... and what is the different between your code and mine?

Comment: Jquery will be called on `onclientclick` , what actually you need as u mentioned *to do thing*

Comment: ya it is my plan B if i cannot get the button name directly.

Comment: @kingyau how your save and update look like , if can give me a clear picture i will be giving you solution in the plan a only

Comment: @kingyau you can use it as hdntext.value but not as text it is one of the state management technique

Answer (score -1):

If you change the Button.Click value, then it will move to a different method onClick;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Name = "btnSubmit";// creating here for intellisense - you would create on your front-end
        bool recordExists = true;

        Button b1 = Controls.Find("btnSubmit", true)[0] as Button;
        //the above is for winforms - you'd have to change for web form
        b1.Text = recordExists ? "Update" : "Save";
        b1.Click += doUpdateOrSave;

    }
    protected void doUpdateOrSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        if (b.Text == "Save")
        {
            //save
        }else
        {
            //update
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's what I'm thinking - what's the problem?

Comment: I agree with other responder - why not change text of button in method - why JQuery? BtnSubmit.ClientID.Text=DoesRecordExist?"Update":"Save";